# pgfplots: shade area between two table-generated curves

Tags: pgfplots, shading, fillbetween

I have three statistical quantiles generated via `\addplot table`. 
I would like to shade the area between the highest and lowest quantiles (the mid one is the median).
If I use `\closedcycle`, I shade all the area until the x axis. The quick solution would probably be the `fillbetween` library, but I got a compilation error (even after having updated the PGFPplots pakckage). Is there an alternative efficient solution to shade between two curves in PGFPlots?

Comment: look for `fillbetween` in the manual of `pgfplots`

Comment: fillbetween is the obvious and easy to use solution. But for some still unknown reason I get the following error when I compile: "! I can't find file `pgflibrarypgfplots.fillbetween.code.tex'." Already updated the pgfplots package. Didn't help much.

Comment: probably your pgfplots is outdated. You can check it via `\pgfplotsversion` command somewhere in your document.

Comment: log file reads: "Package: pgfplots 2013/03/17 v1.8 Data Visualization (1.8-3-gaf58a29)"

Comment: I guess the latest version is 2.1. I'll recheck those updates. Thanks!

Comment: well, I haven't checked the fillbetween approach yet, but the solution via closedcycle was obvious: use closedcycle in the upper bound with a non-white fill option and then again from the lower bound with white fill. Done! :)